# java validator.validate() method takking longer time to validate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have parent and multiple child relation where one parent has many children.
I am using validator.validate method for the validation of parent and child entites as per application functionality.
But its taking longer time to validate and sometimes it gave timeout error.

I refereed this link http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/114639-performance-issues-using-localvalidatorfactorybean and used Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator() [Although i have not yet fully tested but seen performance imrovment butseen some data issue in child records , I am not sure this happened because of single instance of validator I created  ]

xml configuration-->

```
<bean id="validatorFactory" class ="org.springframwork.beanvalidator.LocalValidatorFactoryBean">
<property name="provider" class ="org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator"
```

Java class -->

```
public class MyValidator implements...{

 private Validator validator;

  MyValidator(ValidationFactory factory){
   this.validator=factory.getValidator();
  }

  public void doValidation(){
    //here it is taking lot of time
    validator.validate(objtobevalidated,myvalidationrules);
  }
```

I am using java 1.7,web sphere 8.5

My questions are -

1) I am using hibernate-validator-4.0.jar and it has been provided using WebSphere 8.5 . To improve performance Do I need to use higher hibernate-validator version 4.3 series or 5.0 series

2)As I have created single instance of validator using Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator(), will it validate only single record and will ignore remaing records during validation of parent and its children.

Comment: What kind of performance difference are you experiencing?

Comment: @Todd, after adding code , Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator() , control is moving ahead of method validator.validate(objtobevalidated,myvalidationrules); before this control was not going ahead.

Comment: can anyone suggest in this issue ?